# How to access distanceAttenuationParameters for an SKAudioNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have an SKAudioNode in my scene but the audio from it is not falling off with range as much as I would like (my scene is very large, and when this node is a very long way away it is still clearly audible. Reducing its volume will just then make it too quite when it is at close range - I need to change the fall-off in volume with range).

I can see from the documentation that the parameters I need to adjust are the [distanceAttenuationParameters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioenvironmentnode/1387396-distanceattenuationparameters) in [AVAudioEnvironmentNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioenvironmentnode).

When I look at SKScene I can see that it has an audioEngine [AVAudioEngine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine) property that in turn exposes a mainMixerMode [AVAudioMixer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiomixernode) property. But in none of these places can I find a handle to an [AVAudioEnvironmentNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioenvironmentnode).

So how can I access the parameters needed to make my node's audio behave correctly in a large scene?

Comment: I remember leaving something as an answer to this, but it's gone. Why/Where/How?

Comment: @Confused Yeah, I noticed. Not sure why, where nor how. I deleted my response as it made no sense out of context.

Comment: Other than making a comment about iOS/Apple that wasn't positive, I don't remember anything that might cause that comment to be deleted. And it was, I thought, genuinely helpful for you and anyone else considering audio issues (of which there have been many) in SpriteKit. But none of that irks me. What annoys is that I have no idea who, why, when or how it was deleted. It wasn't me. It wasn't you. And there's no other record of its existence. And I was unaware a comment that was somewhat on topic could even be deleted without any form of notification. Somebody dislikes my writing/thinking.

Comment: @Confused Agreed, I took your comment as humorous but constructive advice and indeed writing my own solution may well be the way I end up going - been there before! Considering some of the stuff that *doesn't* get deleted this was very odd. Perhaps a question on meta to find out what happened?

Comment: I think I'll take it to the memory bank as a reason not to comment. I've had about enough of the draconian ways anything laced with common sense gets handled on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `AVAudioEnvironmentNode` in the `audioEngine`'s `attachedNodes` array. Here is an extension of the `SKScene` that adds a computed property to directly access it from any `SKScene`.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

extension SKScene {
    
    var audioEnvironmentNode : AVAudioEnvironmentNode? {
        audioEngine.attachedNodes.first(where: {audioNode in
            audioNode is AVAudioEnvironmentNode
        }) as? AVAudioEnvironmentNode
    }
    
}
```

Example:

```
if let environmetNode = scene.audioEnvironmentNode {
    environmetNode.distanceAttenuationParameters.distanceAttenuationModel = .linear
    environmetNode.distanceAttenuationParameters.referenceDistance = 400
    environmetNode.distanceAttenuationParameters.maximumDistance = 1500
}
```